# ReactJs - Reuseable Redux Service

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

I understand the concept of Redux's actions, reducers, and mapping to stores.
I have been able to successfully execute Redux into my app.

I was going along merrily using React's contextTypes for child components that needed data from Redux that had been called before.

Then I ran into a strange situation where the data was mutated by a child. When I posted the problem on SO, a member told me I should be using contextTypes sparingly anyway.

So the only way to overcome my problem was map to stores, **AGAIN**, in the child's parent, like a higher component of the parent had done earlier, and pass that data to the child as props.

But that seems all wrong to me. Mapping to the same store again? Why? What am I not understanding? Why do I have to write this on every component that needs the same data another component mapped to?

```
  export default class Foo extends Component {        

  .....

  // I DID THIS STUFF IN A HIGHER COMPONENT.
  // WHY MUST I REPEAT MYSELF AGAIN?
  // WHAT AM I NOT UNDERSTANDING?

  static propTypes = {
    children: PropTypes.node.isRequired,
    dispatch: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
    products: PropTypes.array
  };

  componentDidMount() {
    const { dispatch } = this.props;  
    dispatch(fetchProductsIfNeeded());
  }

  .....

 }
```

---

```
const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
  const {productsReducer } = state;
  if (!productsReducer) {
    return {
      isFetching: false,
      didInvalidate: false,
      error: null,
      products: []
    };
  }

  return {
    error: productsReducer.error,
    isFetching: productsReducer.isFetching,
    didInvalidate: productsReducer.didInvalidate,
    products: productsReducer.products
  };
};

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(Foo);
```

I looked at containers, but it appears to me that containers wrap all dumb components in them at once as such ...

```
   <ProductsContainer>
      <ProductsComponent />
      <ProductSpecialsComponent />
      <ProductsDiscountedComponent />
   </ProductsContainer>
```

And that is not what I want. I thought, like a service I could use that container in each respective dumb component as a such ....

```
   <ProductsContainer>
      <ProductsDiscountedComponent />
   </ProductsContainer>

   <ProductsContainer>
      <ProductSpecialsComponent />
   </ProductsContainer>

   <ProductsContainer>
      <ProductsComponent />
   </ProductsContainer>
```

Right now in order to get my 3 sub components illustrated above, each one of them has to map to stores and that just seems all wrong.

I cannot find anything that I can grasp as a solution.

**Question:**

Is there a way I can map to a particular store **just once**, and call on that "service" for those components that need that data?

If so, examples would be appreciated.

**Post Script:**

I though perhaps if I could perform the 'mapping service' as a pure JavaScript function o/s of react, and just import that function in the components that need it, that would solve the problem, but I have not seen any examples of Redux stores being mapped o/s React.

**UPDATE:**

I posted the solution here ......

[React-Redux - Reuseable Container/Connector](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34817692/react-redux-reuseable-container-connector/34830244#34830244)

Comment: For the solution go here .... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34712755/reactjs-reuseable-redux-service/34830255#34830255

Answer (score 1):

First, an aside about your past problems. It's true that context is not appropriate for something like this. You should also be worried about the mutation you mentioned. If you're using a Redux store, the data that exits it should always be immutable. Perhaps a library like [Immutable.js](https://facebook.github.io/immutable-js/) would help there.

---

Now let's turn to the matter at hand. Perhaps what you aren't fully grokking is what a "dumb" component is. A dumb component should be stateless and a pure:

```js
const Product = ({ name, comments }) => (
  <div>
    <h1>{name}</h1>
    <CommentsList comments={comments} />
  </div>
);
```

The component gets everything it needs from props. Now there are a number of ways to get data into this component, but they are all based on props. For example, the following is the most straightforward:

```js
const ProductList = ({ products }) => (
  <div>
    {products.map( p => <Product product={product} /> )}
  </div>
);

class App extends Component {
  getInitialState () {
    return { products: [] };
  }

  componentDidMount () {
    // connect to store, blah blah...
  }

  render () {
    return (
      <div>
        {/* blah blah */}
        <ProductsList products={this.state.products} />
        {/* blah blah */}
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

As you can see from the example, the entire components tree will get its state from props that are simple passed down from one connection to the store. Aside from `App`, all components are dumb, stateless, and predictable.

But there are also cases where connecting the entire tree through props is impractical and where we need localized connections to our stores. That's where HOCs can be hugely helpful:

```js
const WithProducts = Comp => class WrappedComponent extends Component {
  getInitialState () {
    return { products: [] };
  }

  componentDidMount () {
    // connect to store, blah blah...
  }

  render () {
    return (
      <Comp products={this.state.products} {...this.props} />
    );
  }
}

const ProductListWithProducts = WithProducts( ProductList );
```

Now any component we so wrap will receive the list of products from the store as a prop - no code duplication required. No repeating yourself. Notice how I did not alter the `ProductList` or `Product` components to make this work: those components are too dumb to care.

**The majority of the components in any React app you create should be so dumb.**

---

As another aside, you should *not* be worried about calling your store more than once. If you are worried about that, there's something wrong with the store implementation because calls to stores should be idempotent. You can use actions and so forth to populate the stores, but that should be wholly independent from getting values *from* stores. There should be no performance or network penalty form well-design store retrievals (and, again, using libraries like Immutable can help here too).

Comment: First off, thanks for your help. I'm following along with you comments. Yes, I know what dumb components are, but again, I can't be filling every blessed component with props because a Nth generation child needs those props. I assume "ProductListWithProducts" is the 'service'. How might I implement that on the dumb component?

Comment: The `ProductListWithProducts` is a *composite* component. It renders the dumb component `ProductList` but *extends* it by adding in the store functionality. As I've written it above, it is already implemented on the dumb component. The dumb component *never changes*. As soon as it does, it's no longer dumb. But I'd still note that you'll get calls to your store for every use of the `WithProducts` HOC - and that's as designed. Anyway, there is no "service" like there would be in MVC and I'm not sure what how you're using that term here.